# Mega menu not working same in all browser and breaking responsiveness

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, responsiveness

I'm having a very strange issue with my portfolio website. In Google Chrome browser everything working smoothly, there is no problem. But in other browser like Firefox, Microsoft Edge, Opera Mini, the mega menu is breaking responsiveness.

https://www.nockscript.com/ Go to the website, You'll find a menu called "My Creation" hover it using Chrome browser and check the preview. Do the same thing with Firefox or Microsoft Edge, You'll understand what's the problem.

Note: I'm using WordPress platform, This mega menu comes form theme default design. I want the mega menu preview will show same in all browser as like Chrome browser showing.

Answer (score 0):

In chrome, a javaScript is setting the width of the megamenu to 100% of the available screen size. But for some reason, it's not working in Firefox.

Since you have cache plugins enabled, it's not easy to trace the problem in minified js files. But for sure the problem is in this file:

neuron-core-kyoto / assets / scripts / elementor_{something}.js

You should first disable cache and minify, then find this code inside the above file:

```
$subMenu.css({width:width,left:offset})
```

Then trace what's the value of width and offset and also check if this piece of code is even running in FireFox or not.

---

**Update:**

I've checked your code. It's trying to calculate the width of the page by this:

```
var width=$elementorContainer.outerWidth()-columnPadding*2
```

The problem is made by columnPadding which is extracted with the following code:

```
columnPadding=parseInt($menu.parents('.elementor-column-wrap').css('padding'))
```

The problem is that when you get `css('padding')` in Firefox, it returns `""` and in Chrome, it returns `"0px"`. Then parseInt will convert it to "NaN" in firefox and "0" in Chrome. So the CSS code is not applying in FF.

I've changed the padding to check if the problem is with 0 padding, but its behavior didn't change in Firefox. The thing is that `css('padding-top')` or padding-left, padding-right, padding-bottom are working fine in Firefox.

I've checked this on other sites as well and the same thing was happening there.

I've also found:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3383

Comment: These codes are not working and I deactivate the WP ROCKET plugin which was working for minify. Could you please find out the exact problem now?

Comment: @ArefinBabu Well, I'm still seeing the cached version but figured out what the problem is and updated my answer. Take a look at it. You may change the code from css('padding') to css('padding-left') or calculate the value in another function then use it in your code. Of course your padding is 0, you may even replace columnPadding with Zero. Also, since you are using a premium theme, you may report this to the theme author and ask them to update the code inside their theme.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `position: relative;` on the following classes and set `position:unset` instead:

```
.elementor-element-f666f66,
.elementor-element-f666f66 .elementor-column-wrap,
.elementor-element-f666f66 .elementor-column-wrap .elementor-widget-wrap,
.elementor-element-f666f66 .elementor-column-wrap .elementor-widget-wrap .elementor-widget{
    position: unset !important;
 }
 .m-nav-menu--horizontal ul li.menu-item.menu-item-has-children > ul.sub-menu{
    top: 0 !important;
 }
```

So actualy firefox is respecting the rule of position relative to keep width of the container

Comment: Sorry to say, these codes not working somehow :( do you have any other solutions?

Comment: @ArefinBabu it was my bad, I wrote the last `position: unset;` way wrong. Try again with my edit. I wrote: `.element-f666f66 .elementor-column-wrap .elementor-widget-wrap .elementor-widget` instead of `.elementor-element-f666f66 .elementor-column-wrap .elementor-widget-wrap .elementor-widget` So it was elementor at the beginning

Comment: I added the updated code but nothing happen in the other browser. In Chrome browser the menu has come to the left side which braked Chrome browser responsiveness. Visit the website to see the preview, I still keep the codes

Comment: @ArefinBabu css did not update, it seems to be the same with the exact same error

Comment: DO NOT OFFER THAT on internet.

Comment: Can you push it with the code update, like this I could see the result

Comment: Do you have any other solution like how I can fix it?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out the issue! Nothing working

Comment: Even with applying .elementor-element-f666f66 `.elementor-column-wrap .elementor-widget-wrap .elementor-widget{
    position: unset !important;
 }` ?

Comment: I've solved the solution through these codes but it created new 4 issues!

.elementor-21285 .elementor-element.elementor-element-6ac0082 nav > ul li.menu-item-has-children ul.sub-menu{
 margin-top: 31px !important;
 overflow: hidden !important;
}
.elementor-21285 .elementor-element.elementor-element-6ac0082 nav > ul li.menu-item-has-children ul.sub-menu{
width: 1290px !important;
right: -267px !important;
}

ul.sub-menu.m-mega-menu-holder{
 left: auto !important
}

So I think this is not a professional way to fix the error!

Comment: Please update your posts with 4 issues as it is unreadable in comment. (Professional wont use wordpress.)

Comment: Haha, Yes professional won't use WordPress but I don't know why I love WordPress. Anyway, I'm using a premium theme and I'm trying to contact with support team. It must be a theme bug. Anyway, Thank you so much for your help #MaxiGui - You tried your level best :)

Comment: I did my best with live website